# Find $\sup\{\sin(\theta) | \theta \in [0,\pi]\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose you have the following:

$A=\{\sin(\theta)|\theta \in [0,\pi]\}$

I need to find $\sup A$ and $\inf A$ and I need to answer if these are in $A$, but I'm having trouble finding out, how I should approach this.

I know that $\sup$ is the lowest number that is bigger or equal to all other numbers in $A$, but then since $\sin(\pi)=0$ then the highest number must be $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$ and then the lowest number must be $\sin(0)=0$. So by that logic:

$\sup A = 1$

$\inf A = 0$

But my problem is, that I'm not certain that this is correct. So I'm posting here to find out if I have misunderstood something about the prospects of $\sup$ and $\inf$ or if I'm on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

Note that $a\leq1$ for every $a\in A$, i.e. $1$ is an upper bound of $A$, and secondly that for every $\epsilon<1$ we have $\epsilon<1\in A$, so $A$ has no smaller upper bound. That means that $1$ is the least upper bound of $A$. Notation $\sup A=1$.

Note that $a\geq0$ for every $a\in A$, i.e. $0$ is a lower bound of $A$, and secondly that for every $\epsilon>0$ we can find some $a\in A$ with $a<\epsilon$, so A has no larger lower bound. That means that $0$ is the greatest lower bound of $A$. Notation $\inf A=0$.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the response, but if I may, I have another question? Are these bounds in $A$? Since this is an open interval doesn't that mean that the end points aren't in A? So by that: $\sup A$ is in A, but $\inf A$ isn't? Or I'm I wrong?

Comment: You are correct in observing that $\sup A=1\in A$ and $\inf A=0\notin A$. Actually we have $A=(0,1]$ here.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for clarification and help!

Comment: You are welcome.